# Facebook not redirecting on home page after sign in (Facebook Authentication)?

Tags: oauth, facebook, oauth-2.0

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
              appId:'MY_APP_ID', cookie:true,
              status:true, xfbml:true
           });
  </script>
<div id="login-box">
  <fb:login-button perms="email,offline_access" redirect_uri="http://mydomain.com:8000/home/">
         Facebook
  </fb:login-button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It asks the user to allow the privileges, but it doesn't redirect to the `redirect_uri` page after successfully allowing the application by the user and remains on the same page.

This is part of a django application.

Comment: Have you tried url encoding the `redirect_uri`? (`http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%3A8000%2Fhome%2F`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to use the on-login parameter to redirect:

```
<fb:login-button perms="email,offline_access" on-login="window.location = 'http://www.example.com';">Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: In your case, how would I get the access code. Facebook doesn't pass the access_code in your case.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try adding

```
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: 'appid',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });

        // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location="your redirect";
        });
      };
  </script>
```

Comment: How will you get the access_code, since in your case facebook doesnt returns any access_code !